# Command not found in if-else statement

Tags: puppet

I have some function, that do chroot into some directory. I execute this command twice with `exec` type if `if-else` statement. First time I execute command in `then` section, and second time — in `else` with some others parameters. While `if` returns `true` — all is good, but if it returns `false` so I recieve error such `chroot not found`.
My part of code:

```
define manage_users($some_variables)
{
    some code here ...

    if $action == "create" {
        $command = "..."
        exec {"${nsenter} && chroot ${some_dir} /bin/bash -c '${some_command}'":
            path    => ["/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/bin"],
        }
    } #delete user
    else {
        some code ....

        exec { "${nsenter} && chroot ${some_dir} /bin/bash -c '${some_other_command}'":
            path    => ["usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/bin"],
            onlyif  => "...",
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong in `else`? It's seems to me the same as in `then`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path:

```
            path    => ["usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/bin"],
```

That should be:

```
            path    => ["/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/bin"],
```

Notice the added `/` at `usr/sbin`.
Which makes sense, since it's `/usr/sbin/chroot`.